# how to stub aws s3 upload with sinon

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, mocha.js, sinon

How to stubbing S3 upload in Node.js?

I'm using Mocha and Sinon. And I have a file that exports a class instance that including the upload method. It looks like this:

```
// storage.ts
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import archiver from 'archiver';
import retry from 'bluebird-retry';


export class Storage {
  private readonly s3: AWS.S3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: MINIO_ENDPOINT,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    s3ForcePathStyle: true,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
  });
  private readonly uploadBucket: string = UPLOAD_BUCKET;
  private readonly downloadBucket: string = DOWNLOAD_BUCKET;

  public async upload(localPath: string, s3Key: string, onProgress: (progress: number) => void): Promise<void> {
    await retry(async () => { // Be careful, it will influence stub.
      const stat = fse.statSync(localPath);
      let readable: stream.Readable;
      let archive: archiver.Archiver | undefined;
      if (stat.isFile()) {
        readable = fse.createReadStream(localPath);
      } else {
        archive = archiver('zip', { zlib: { level: 0 } }).directory(localPath, false);
        readable = archive;
      }
      const request = this.s3.upload({ Bucket: this.uploadBucket, Key: s3Key, Body: readable });
      request.on('httpUploadProgress', ({ loaded }) => {
        onProgress(loaded);
      });
      if (archive) {
        archive.finalize().catch(console.error);
      }

      await request.promise().catch((err) => {
        fse.removeSync(localPath);
        throw err;
      });
    }, { max_tries: UPLOAD_RETRY_TIMES, throw_original: true });
  }

}

export const storage = new Storage();
```

I try to stub this upload method in my unit test, it looks like:

```
import { storage } from './storage';
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('Storage', () => {
  let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;

  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('upload', async () => {

    const s3Stub = sandbox.stub(AWS.S3.prototype, 'upload'); // something wrong

    await storage.upload(
      './package.json',
      's3Key',
      uploadBytes => { return uploadBytes; });

    expect(s3Stub).to.have.callCount(1);
    s3Stub.restore();

  });
});
```

And I got an error:

```
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

I want to test the upload method , but do not upload file to s3 really.

How should I do ?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable `esModuleInterop: true` config in your `tsconfig.json` file and change the `import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'` to `import AWS from 'aws-sdk'`.

Since the `new Storage()` statement will execute instantly when you import the this module, you should import the `./storage.ts` module after you stub `AWS.S3` class.

P.S. *I deleted the code not related to the problem*

E.g.

`storage.ts`:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const UPLOAD_BUCKET = 'UPLOAD_BUCKET';
const MINIO_ENDPOINT = 'MINIO_ENDPOINT';
const AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID';
const AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY';

export class Storage {
  private readonly s3: AWS.S3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: MINIO_ENDPOINT,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    s3ForcePathStyle: true,
    signatureVersion: 'v4',
  });
  private readonly uploadBucket: string = UPLOAD_BUCKET;

  public async upload(localPath: string, s3Key: string, onProgress: (progress: number) => void): Promise<void> {
    const request = this.s3.upload({ Bucket: this.uploadBucket, Key: s3Key, Body: '123' });
  }
}

export const storage = new Storage();
```

`storage.test.ts`:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
import sinon from 'sinon';

describe('68431461', () => {
  let sandbox: sinon.SinonSandbox;

  before(() => {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('should pass', async () => {
    const s3InstanceStub = { upload: sandbox.stub() };
    const s3Stub = sandbox.stub(AWS, 'S3').callsFake(() => s3InstanceStub);
    const { storage } = await import('./storage');
    const onProgressStub = sandbox.stub();
    await storage.upload('./package.json', 's3Key', onProgressStub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(s3Stub);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(s3InstanceStub.upload);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  68431461
    ✓ should pass (796ms)


  1 passing (810ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 storage.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I run your test code in my computer, but got an error "Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves". It's strange.

Comment: @Rife It may be affected by other code with side effects. You did not create stubs for them. As a result, their original implementation is still used during the test execution process, and HTTP requests, RPC calls, etc. may be initiated. You need to locate the issue firstly, and try to stub them.

Comment: I found it, the code with side effects is `retry` (bluebird-retry), I removed it in my question.